# Enumerate all the combinations given a constraint

Tags: combinatorics

Assume there are $N$ non-negative integer numbers: $a_1,\ldots,a_N$. How can one enumerate all the possible combinations of $(a_1,\ldots,a_N)$ which satisfy the following inequality:

$\sum _{n=1}^N a_n S_n \leq C$

where $S_n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the cost corresponding to $a_n$ and $C$ is a constant number.

Examples:

$(0,0,\ldots,0)$

$(1,0,\ldots,0)$

$(2,0,\ldots,0)$

$\vdots$

$([\frac{C}{S_1}],0,\ldots,0)$

$(1,1,\ldots,0)$

Comment: I am not sure if there is an efficient method for arbitary $S_n$'s and $C$. I guess, there is none. Are there any more restrictions besides $S_n\ge 0$ ?

Comment: If you are looking for an algorithm, there is one. Try using recursion.

Comment: Since all the $a_n$'s are bounded, you can enumerate the solutions with $N$ nested loops as well.

Comment: @Peter I thought of that. But $N$ is around 23. So, having 23 nested loops is not a practical solution.

Comment: This is a variation of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), known to be NP-hard. Searching for that will find many hits.

Comment: @Sina, you can avoid 23 nested loops by using recursion. That way, you can make your N a variable (doesn't have to be fixed, e.g. 23).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://pastebin.com/c6tnpudQ) is a sample program I wrote with 
$C=35$, $N=2$ and the weights $S_1=3$ and $S_2=4$.
You can try pasting it and compiling it [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php). You can change the capacity C, the number of coordinates N and the weights. Just be sure to leave the program consistent, otherwise it would not produce a correct result.

In short, I am using a recursive function $rec$ to successively "fill" the capacity C. The for-loop inside the function $rec$ tries all possible values $i$ for the current coordinate $N$ before moving to the next one with the remaining capacity $C-iS[N]$.

Warning: Changing the number of coordinates to 23 may require the program a lot of time to finish depending on the capacity. The algorithm is optimal in the sense that it processes only the valid configurations.